# Data collection freeware for Trimble

Tags: gratis, open-source, gis

Does anyone know of any free software that can be used to collect GIS data in the field on Windows Embedded Handheld systems?

I am using Trimble Juno T41/5 devices.

Ideally I want to then be able to use the data in ArcGIS 9 or 10 on Windows PC. 
I would choose ArcMap, but I work for a nonprofit that cannot afford the price tag of $1800 per device!